# Identify vacuum hoses at rear of intake manifold on 2003 Cadillac CTS

Tags: part-identification, cadillac, cts, vacuum-hoses

My 2003 Cadillac CTS has 4 vacuum hoses at the rear of a plastic cover on top of the intake manifold. You can see them near the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5oxPj-wgW0) The mechanic leaves the cover dangling from the tubes I'm asking about.

I'd like to know where they go and what they do. I've looked online for a diagram or other explanation, but apparently I don't know enough to formulate a good Google query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a diagram from the service manual. Searching, "2003 Cadillac CTS Vacuum Diagram" provides similar results.

[image]

Comment: If I'm reading that right, That's 14 - 13 - 12 - 14,(EVAP and Crankcase.)

Comment: @TecBrat Correct

Comment: As to the "provides similar results", The diagram is somewhat abstract compared to the real life setup and I couldn't recognize it for what it was. Thanks for bridging that gap for me.